# Attachments to infopath list form

Tags: infopath, attachments, sharepoint-list

i created a list, then in the ribbon went to customize in infopath. There i created a form. The form will go through a few different steps where different people will review then add an attachment. However infopath only lets me put one unique attachment field. If i pit another, it is bound. This makes the form look bad because in the three different sections that have attachments, it shows all attachments. How can i have it so the first person attaches a form. Then the second person can attach a form but not have a list of the previous users attachments showing?

Answer (score 1):

Lists only have one attachment field. You could create a InfoPath form library. This would store the data as an xml file in the library, rather than in a list. This mechanism also supports multiple attachment controls, each bound to their own field (or, a repeating field that stores multiple items). Before you go down this road, please be aware that the form size, including attachments, has a [max](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/15422067-increase-the-4mb-infopath-file-attachment-limit-fo) of 4MB. This limit can be customized in on-prem SharePoint servers, but not SharePoint Online.

If the form's main purpose is to gather multiple attachments, then perhaps check into using a document set instead. Document sets are like folders, but they support metadata, as well as approval and workflows.

Also, standard infopath warning: this is an older tool, and you're better off working with the newer tools in you're in SharePoint online, such as power apps. (though, power apps will have the same limit in that there is only one attachment field.)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  After explaining to the client some of the intricacies of InfoPath I have posted another question that is more specific for the requirements.  Thanks again